# Keycloak Gatekeeper does not set X-Auth header correctly

Tags: shell, sh, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I try to use a shell script to login to a web application secured by Keycloak Gatekeeper.
The login is working and the token handle shows the correct data.
But when I do the "real" request the X-Auth-* headers are not existing, so the upstream application is not able to check the authorization.

```sh
# login
wget --save-cookies .cookie --keep-session-cookies -qO/dev/null --post-data='username=...&password=...' "$URL/oauth/login"
# verify the token data (correct)
wget --load-cookies .cookie -q  -O- "$URL/oauth/token"
# request data (no X-Auth headers present)
wget --load-cookies .cookie -nv -O- "$URL/path/to/data"
```

When doing the login via the Code Flow via the browser the headers are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`X-Auth-*` headers are added to the request `from the gatekeeper to the upstream app`. You are checking `user - gatekeeper` connection, so it is correct, that these headers are not there.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong, I checked the correct thing. But the solution was so simple, I white-listed the url. Ouch.

Comment: @user3775041 you need https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to get correct answer